# jqGrid - Custom button on form not being removed

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a few grids on my page. In one of them I have a custom edit form with a custom button (Testar Conexão) like this:

[image]

I've made a logic to remove all the customized fields and button and create them again everytime the user clicks on edit. If I click to edit a row on this grid, it works properly (the customized button shows up only one time), but the problem happens when I click to edit a row from another grid and then click to edit a row on this grid. This is what happens: 
[image]

The button gets replicated everytime I click to edit. Here is my code:

```
 beforeShowForm: function(form) {
    /* editouServico is a global boolean variable 
     * that checks if user has already clicked on the button. 
     * If it's true, then I remove all the fields and button. 
     * If false, it just creates all the fields and button.
    */
    if(editouServico) { 
        //remove fields and button
        $('#tr_servidor').remove();
        $('#tr_porta').remove();
        $('#tr_nomeBanco').remove();
        $('#tr_usuario').remove();
        $('#tr_senha').remove();
        $('#botaoTestarConexao').remove();
        alert('removeu');
    }
    //create fields
    $('<tr style="" rowpos="4" class="FormData" id="tr_servidor"> <td class="CaptionTD">Servidor</td><td class="DataTD">&nbsp;<input id="servidor" type="text" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>').insertAfter(linhaCodigo);    
    var linhaServidor = $('#tr_servidor', form).show();
    $('<tr style="" rowpos="5" class="FormData" id="tr_porta"> <td class="CaptionTD">Porta</td><td class="DataTD">&nbsp;<input id="porta" type="text" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>').insertAfter(linhaServidor);    
    var linhaPorta = $('#tr_porta', form).show();
    $('<tr style="" rowpos="6" class="FormData" id="tr_nomeBanco"> <td class="CaptionTD">Banco</td><td class="DataTD">&nbsp;<input id="banco" type="text" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>').insertAfter(linhaPorta);    
    var linhaBanco = $('#tr_nomeBanco', form).show();
    $('<tr style="" rowpos="7" class="FormData" id="tr_usuario"> <td class="CaptionTD">Usuário</td><td class="DataTD">&nbsp;<input id="usuario" type="text" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>').insertAfter(linhaBanco);    
    var linhaUsuario = $('#tr_usuario', form).show();
    $('<tr style="" rowpos="8" class="FormData" id="tr_senha"> <td class="CaptionTD">Senha</td><td class="DataTD">&nbsp;<input id="senha" type="password" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></td></tr>').insertAfter(linhaUsuario);  

    //create button
    $('<a href="#" id="botaoTestarConexao" >Testar Conexão<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-transferthick-e-w"></span></a>')
    .click(function() { 
        ... 
    }).addClass("fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all fm-button-icon-left")
      .prependTo("#Act_Buttons>td.EditButton");

    editouServico=true; 
}
```

as you can see in my code, I've put an alert to see if the code gets in there and it does..

PS: editouServico starts with value false and is set to false everytime I recreate my grid

Comment: But you're not showing the custom button code - you show one button.  Where is "Enviar" (I presume this is the problem button)?

Comment: I've edited my post to make it clearer. But answering your question: my custom button is "Testar Conexão".

Comment: I think I need to see more code.  Do you create a new `form` each time?  Do you remove `form` after?  I suspect that the `$('#botaoTestarConexao').remove();` does not actually remove the node.  Add debug: `console.log('length', $('#botaoTestarConexao').length);` before and after you remove.  Another possibility is that this method is being called multiple times.

Comment: Actually, the creation and deletion of the form is made by jqGrid automatically, but I think it doesn't create a new form each time because if I don't remove() the fields on the form, it just keeps incrementing. The most strange thing is that the button doesn't get removed ONLY when I've clicked to edit a row from another grid before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it looking out for the id of the grid, so that it doesn't get "confused" on where to add/remove the button. Also, I changed the way I was removing.

My code now is:

```
.addClass("fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all fm-button-icon-left")
      .prependTo("#TblGrid_grid_servico_2 > tbody > tr#Act_Buttons > td.EditButton");`
```

instead of

`.addClass("fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all fm-button-icon-left")
      .prependTo("#Act_Buttons>td.EditButton");`

And

```
$('#botaoTestarConexao').removeClass("fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all fm-button-icon-left").remove();
```

instead of

```
$('#botaoTestarConexao').remove();
```